# Get property name of object in closure advanced compiling?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

**Background**

I have an array of objects that are all the same type.

I've created a class for handling lookups on arrays of all the same type. The point of the class is to prevent iterating through the array more than you need to each time you look for an object based on it's property.

The bare bones of my lookup class looks something like this. So you can understand what it does.

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {Array} items An array of all the same type of item.
 */
titan.structs.IndexedLookup = function (items) {};

/**
 * Get by property
 * @param {String} property The property name.
 * @param {String|Number} value The property value.
 * @returns {Object|null}
 */
titan.structs.IndexedLookup.prototype.getByProperty = 
function (property, value) {};
```

**Problem**

I want use the last line of this

```
var lookup = new titan.structs.IndexedLookup(myArrayOfItems);
// Lookup by property 'id'
var item = lookup.getByProperty("id", 27);
```

I can't think of any clever way of getting the actual property name that the advanced compiler has assigned instead of "id".

**Remarks**

I'm not looking for a solution of using properties in quotes on the object types as that requires prior knowledge when designing the object class that it will be used as a lookup property later in some unknown component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of solutions:

Two approaches that prevent renaming:

- use property quoting consistently:

  ```
  item['id'] = 2;
  lookup.getByProperty('id', 2);
  ```
- add an extern declaration:

  ```
  Object.prototype.id;
  ```

Two approaches that allow renaming:

- Add a declaration for JSCompiler_renameProperty like:

  ```
  function JSCompiler_renameProperty(prop) { return prop }
  ```

and use it like so:

```
lookup.getByProperty(JSCompiler_renameProperty("id"), 27);
```

this is not good does work well with type based optimizations.

- Use goog.reflect.object from the closure library:

  ```
  var idPropName = (goog.object.transpose(goog.reflect.object(MyType, id: 1)))[1];
  ```

This allows you to specify the type associated with the property and works well with the type based optimizations.

Comment: The prevent renaming isn't really an ideal solution for me as it would mean going back and editing my object types when I know what other classes will use what property (which could be different for different classes). I like the look of using `JSCompiler_renameProperty` and will get back to you once I'm able to give it a go. And the `goog.reflect.object` is new to me, I've been handling object types differently with advanced compilation, so this will be very useful. Cheers.

Comment: If you use type based optimizations you don't need to rename uses in unrelated classes that use the same property name.  You would however need a host type other than Object.  @interface declarations work well for this (and then declare the classes as implementing this external interface).  This kind of disambiguation relies on sufficient and distinguishing type information and so isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult probblem and there isn't a great solution out there. You can view some of the discussions: [Tests for Property Existance with Renaming](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=983)

Normally I find ways to refactor my code to handle the problem differently.

I encourage you to open an issue in the Closure-compiler project requesting a feature supporting this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added my use case to the comments on that issue.